# Html Element not displaying on FireFox but displaying on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am stuck on an issue where i was working with an individual component (simple dropzone). However its working fine on chrome, its css is fine.

Css

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 50%;
}

.inputDnD {
  .form-control-file {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 6em;
    outline: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #c61c23;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px solid currentColor;
    &:before {
      content: attr(data-title);
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 6em;
      line-height: 2em;
      padding-top: 1.5em;
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      text-align: center;
      border: 0.25em dashed currentColor;
      transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
      overflow: visible;
    }
    &:hover {
      &:before {
        border-style: solid;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0.25em currentColor;
      }
    }
  }
}

// PRESENTATIONAL CSS
body {
  background-color: #1F1F1F;
}
```

**Problem**:
The problem is on firefox, where its not displaying. I Have applied css, not sure if i added css correctly.

If someone have any idea about the Firefox not displaying due to position, please help me out.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: When you got an error message telling you to put your code in the question and not to just link to CodePen, that mean you should put **your code** in the question and not mark a random paragraph as code to bypass the check.

Comment: You appear to be putting a before pseudo element on an input element. This isn't strictly allowed though Chrome is lenient I don't think FF is in this regard. Put the pseudo element on for example a related label.

Comment: @Quentin you are right, sorry i edited the question.

Comment: @AHaworth thanks for reply, sorry i could not understand,

Comment: Code Pen : https://codepen.io/bloxxite/pen/bGNeLxd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the invalid CSS:

```
 // PRESENTATIONAL CSS
```

The Firefox CSS parser is not recovering from the error without consuming the next line providing background color for the `body` element. My experience is that Firefox will resume parsing after the next `;` or perhaps `}` in order to bypass errors that have been encountered.

The solution of course is to use a CSS comment:

```
/* PRESENTATIONAL CSS */
```

---

*update:*

Checking the console (in Firefox) reveals additional errors:

```
.inputDnD {
   .form-control-file {
```

shows that `.form-control-file {` is not a valid CSS property name. Microsoft Edge, also a webkit browser, confirms multiple problems with the validity of the CSS. I suggest correcting the CSS before continuing.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i dont think its css comment issue, please see this pen

Comment: I visited the pen and copied the code for local testing (without the JavaScript for dropping files). The file input appeared as expected. If you wish to clarify "it's not displaying" please update the question with details of the expected and actual results you are unhappy with in Firefox: "works fine" in Chrome contains no informational content.

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes you are right. i am gonna have to fix the css.